# How to fix the error unknown unexpected option: --docker?

Tags: docker, vercel

I'm trying to build and deploy a project from GitHub (the [following](https://github.com/geshan/laravel-zeit-now)) using ZEIT Now hosting service using `docker`.

I followed the instructions in the `readme.md` of the GitHub project and as soon as i get to the fourth step:

> now --public --docker (you might need to login once)

I get the following error:

`"> Error! Unknown or unexpected option: --docker"`

I installed Docker Toolbox (I'm running Windows 7 x64) and the docker command seems to be working normally in the command prompt, i've used it to identify the docker version i have which is `18.03.0-ce`

I'm new to this so sorry if i'm getting anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

V2 accounts of Now.sh doesn't support Docker deployments.